# mdns: is there a web-service interface to avahi-daemon?

Tags: linux, mdns, avahi

I would like to query the mdns database of avahi-daemon through HTTP. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having spent some time with the source code and not having stumble on the functionality mentioned above, I believe that the current Avahi (0.6.23) does not implement nor exposes such feature.

Comment: but why one would need one? one doesn't look for (global) DNS to provide HTTP interface (to make world-wide requests), now mDNS is just "local DNS" and distributed too, so every client responds on own behalf. There are other arguments against http backend. Use avahi-browse and avahi-browse-domains CLI tools, they're enough for basic browsing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not HTML, but there is avahi-discover for Linux, https://packages.debian.org/buster/avahi-discover.
[image]